# Need help converting WMI values to VBScript variables

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I am not a programmer, but I am trying to extend the amount of information that Bginfo can collect from a computer by using VBScripts.  I've got some of it working, but some WMI queries return multiple lines of values.  I'd like to split these multiple lines up so I can use them separately.  Here's an example that I partially created from WMIGen:

```
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly       = &h20

strComputer = "."


Dim Installed
Dim Size


Set objWMIService = GetObject( "winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/cimv2" )
Set colSlots = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly )
Set colMem = objWMIService.ExecQuery( "SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly )

On Error Resume Next

For Each objSlot In colSlots
    TotalSlots = objSlot.MemoryDevices
Next

For Each objMem In colMem
    MemDevices = objMem.DeviceLocator
    PartNumbers = objMem.PartNumber
    Size = Round(objMem.Capacity / 1073741824) & " GB"
Next

On Error Goto 0
```

MemDevices, PartNumbers, and Size all gives me multiple lines of results depending on how many memory devices there are.  How can I get the value for for each line individually and make them into variables?  Here is what I was thinking about for how it would look:

```
RAM 1: Size in GB, Part Number, slot number on board.
RAM 2: Size in GB, Part number, slot number on board
"" Continue the list for the remaining RAM sticks ""
```

Comment: Could you please share a screenshot with `MemDevices`, `PartNumbers` and `Size` actual output for you, and output you expect. I've tried the code, and it shows exactly what is in each slot including part number and size.

Comment: I know there's nothing wrong with the code.  For example, if you have 4 DIMMS, the MemDevices query returns 4 lines.  What I want to do is learn how to turn each one of those lines into variables.  That way I can list each slot separately in Bginfo with its size, part number and slot number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an undefined number of variables of same type you could use an array variable in VBScript.
For using with Bginfo utility is not necessary that variable.
You can generate information on loop:

```
i = 1
For Each objMem In colMem
    MemDevices = objMem.DeviceLocator
    PartNumbers = objMem.PartNumber
    Size = Round(objMem.Capacity / 1073741824) & " GB"
    Echo "RAM " & i & " Size: " & Size & " Part Nr. " & PartNumbers
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: @Ansgar Scripts for Bginfo utility are special. You must use "echo" sentence instead "wscript.echo". Check [this page](https://www.verboon.info/2012/02/how-to-use-vbscripts-in-bginfo/)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for!  Another related question I have:  Let's say I wanted to only display the information for RAM 2, but exclude all of the other RAMS.  If I know there are at least two RAMS, but I don't know the exact total number, how would I display only RAM 2?

Comment: `If i = 2 Then     Echo "RAM " & i & " Size: " & Size & " Part Nr. " & PartNumbers  End If `  Check [if statement syntax](https://ss64.com/vb/if.html)

Comment: Thanks JoSerra.  The only problem I am having is after the listing the first slot, Bginfo indents the rest of the lines, which is the same problem this guy had:  [link](http://sysinternals32.rssing.com/browser.php?indx=7466651&item=1328).    Doesn't seem like this can be fixed through the script though.

Comment: Hi @Chris ; this is a Bginfo specific question (not about vbscript). You can try using another font type / aligment in Bginfo. Sorry.